# Excel: Evaluate a cell given values specified in other cells

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that is basically a giant formula. It takes one main input (representing gross income), runs through a waterfall of cells calculating things like adjusted gross income, taxable income, federal income tax, state income tax, payroll tax, etc. etc., to final arrive at one final number (representing total taxes) in a single cell.

I would like to substitute different values into that input cell and record the value that would result in the output cell. For example, imagine I have 10 years of income figures in cells A1:A10. In B1:B10 I want to get the total taxes that would result from running those income figures into that giant tax calculator sheet and collecting the final figure.

Is this possible in Excel/Google Sheet?

Comment: yes it is. what have you tried so far?

Comment: When I first did this, I just kept all the calculations in one single column. Top cell would be the main input (gross income) and bottom cell would be the main output (total taxes). Then I just entered different values in the first row and dragged everything below it to the right to get the right output values in the bottom row. This works but is really unreadable. What I'd really like is to have a dedicated sheet that does all the tax calculations, and basically just treat that entire sheet as a function f. Then on a different sheet have one row specifying x1, ...; in another row f(x1), ...

Comment: What you need is a data table   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-e95e2487-6ca6-4413-ad12-77542a5ea50b

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Do you know if there's a similar function in Google Sheet? Can't seem to find it. :(